# Multiple FULL OUTER JOIN on multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, full-outer-join

I have multiple outer joins

```
SELECT  A.column2
        , B.column2
        , C.column2
FROM 
(
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table1) A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table2) B on A.month= B.month
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table3) C on A.month= C.month
)
```

Now the last join is having a problem, its repeating when month of A is more than B but if B has more month that A we have OUTER JOIN in C with month of A which now repeats, so I guess having a FULL OUTER JOIN within two table might solve the problem?? Any indepth links??

**Sample Data(Incorrect)**

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║  Revenue   ║ Budget  ║ ActualMonth ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║     6.9172 ║ 3.5046  ║ Jan         ║
║     7.3273 ║ 3.7383  ║ Feb         ║
║     7.3273 ║ 3.9719  ║ Mar         ║
║     7.2726 ║ 4.2056  ║ Apr         ║
║     7.2595 ║ 6.7757  ║ May         ║
║     7.2726 ║ 6.7757  ║ Jun         ║
║     0.41   ║ 0.00    ║ Jul         ║
║     0.41   ║ 0.00    ║ Aug         ║
║     0.41   ║ 0.00    ║ Sep         ║
║     0.41   ║ 0.00    ║ Oct         ║
║     7.4696 ║ 0.00    ║ Nov         ║
║     7.4696 ║ 0.00    ║ Dec         ║
║     0.00   ║ 9.3457  ║ Sep         ║
║     0.00   ║ 16.3551 ║ Dec         ║
║     0.00   ║ 6.3084  ║ Jul         ║
║     0.00   ║ 14.0186 ║ Oct         ║
║     0.00   ║ 16.3551 ║ Nov         ║
║     0.00   ║ 6.1915  ║ Aug         ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Correct Data**

```
╔════════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║  Revenue   ║ Budget  ║ ActualMonth ║
╠════════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║     6.9172 ║ 3.5046  ║ Jan         ║
║     7.3273 ║ 3.7383  ║ Feb         ║
║     7.3273 ║ 3.9719  ║ Mar         ║
║     7.2726 ║ 4.2056  ║ Apr         ║
║     7.2595 ║ 6.7757  ║ May         ║
║     7.2726 ║ 6.7757  ║ Jun         ║
║     0.41   ║ 6.3084  ║ Jul         ║
║     0.41   ║ 6.1915  ║ Aug         ║
║     0.41   ║ 9.3457  ║ Sep         ║
║     0.41   ║ 14.0186 ║ Oct         ║
║     7.4696 ║ 16.3551 ║ Nov         ║
║     7.4696 ║ 16.3551 ║ Dec         ║
╚════════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output.

Comment: The outer joins are commutative. `A outer join B outer join C` is the same as `A outer join C outer join B`. In fact it is even the same as `A outer join (B outer join C)`  I don't understand your problem *(note: this applies since both B and C join to A)*

Comment: Please check the sample data

Comment: how about adding a where condition? `WHERE Revenue>0`

Comment: What is the goal of your query?

Comment: its actually a bar chart with basemonth as X-axis and revenue as Y-axis with budget as line bar

Comment: @techdo: I guess where Revenue>0 wont work coz we might actually get zero value too

Comment: Please add table1, table2 and table3 data. OR you just need a query on the sample data given?

Comment: You probably need months table over entire possible history, this way you could use left joins. Another way would be writing last join condition like c.month=isnull(a.month,b.month) - I've not tried, but this should exclude some unneeded combinations.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
SELECT  A.column2
        , B.column2
        , C.column2
FROM 
(
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table1) A
    FULL OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table2) B on A.month= B.month
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table3) C on ISNULL(A.month, B.month) = C.month
)
```

Comment: this should fix your issue with C. Feel free to use the same logic (ISNULL) with B if needed.

Comment: depending on environment, is the ISNULL() equivalent to coalesce or oracle's NVL()? Does joining on NVL(A.ID, B.ID) = C.ID operate the same way

Comment: I think it would be useful to add that if you have more than 3 tables you want to do a full outer join on, you either have to start nesting `ISNULL`, or you can just use `COALESCE` instead, which should work on all standard compliant databases.

Comment: i originally had an or in my join clause, but this saved me orders of magnitude on performance.

Answer (score 27):

One of the ways to do this could be create "anchor" table from all possible data from all three tables and then use `left outer join`:

```
select
    A.column2,
    B.column2,
    C.column2
from (
    select distinct month from table1
    union
    select distinct month from table2
    union
    select distinct month from table3
) as X
    left outer join table1 as A on A.month = X.month
    left outer join table2 as B on B.month = X.month
    left outer join table3 as C on C.month = X.month
```

Comment: This is a great answer and perfectly fitted my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Great answer, easily readable. I attempted extending it to the case where there are records at several dates and the amounts were not summed by month yet. So far, there is some error in my code for the summed amounts: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282958/get-monthly-sums-from-several-tables-with-same-date-amount-columns

Comment: Great answer Roman. This solution is very simple

Answer (score 10):

Use option with [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) function to determine a column grouping.

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.Month, t2.Month, t3.Month) AS Month, 
       SUM(ISNULL(t1.Col1, 0)) AS t1Col1, 
       SUM(ISNULL(t2.Col1, 0)) AS t2Col1, 
       SUM(ISNULL(t3.Col1, 0)) AS t3Col1
FROM dbo.table1 t1 FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.table2 t2 ON t1.Month = t2.Month
                   FULL OUTER JOIN dbo.table3 t3 ON t1.Month = t3.Month
GROUP BY COALESCE(t1.Month, t2.Month, t3.Month)
```

Answer (score 5):

I can think of 2 ways off the bat that you can address this, depending on what the actual logic is to define the results you want.

The first, and most fool-proof way, is to use GROUP BY month, and use aggregate functions like MAX(column2) to get the non-zero rows only, or if there are multiple non-zero rows you want to add, use SUM().   This is the best solution if there is an aggregate function that fulfills your logical intent.

Another is to include more conditions in your JOIN, like "WHERE a.month=b.month AND b.column2 > 0", but that still won't solve the problem if there can be more than one non-zero row.

Comment: I agree with Tab, use GROUP BY and SUM() or MAX()

Answer (score 2):

something like

```
select month, sum(a) a,  sum(b) b, sum(c) c from (
  SELECT month, column2 A, 0 B, 0 C FROM table1 
    union 
  SELECT month, 0 A, column2 B, 0 C FROM table2
    union 
  SELECT month, 0 A, 0 B, column2 C FROM table3
) x
group by month
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing all the outer joins at once, how about doing them one at a time like this:

```
SELECT  A.column2
        , B.column2
        , C.column2
FROM 
(
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM (
        (SELECT month, column2 FROM table1) A
        FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT month, column2 FROM table2) B on A.month= B.month
    )) A_AND_B
    FULL OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT month, column2 FROM table3) C on A_AND_B.month= C.month
)
```

i.e., do full outer join on A and B, then do full outer join of **that** and C, then do full outer join of **that** and D, then do full outer join of **that** and E, etc.

This is less complex than the other answers above and can be repeated for as many tables as you'd like to full outer join.