# joining three tables between each other

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to join three tables in this way .

```
select T1.[...],T2.[...],T3.[...]
from T1 
full outer join T2 on T1.[key]=T2.[key]
full outer join T3 on T1.[key]=T3.[key]
full outer join T2 on T2.[key]=T3.[key]
```

My question is : Is this a valid Form?
And if no is there a way to do such operation?

Comment: Try it and find out! :)

Comment: Why are you repeating `t2` twice?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I need to match T1 and T2 with T3 or it won't show me all records

Comment: There is a big difference between "valid" (however you interpret it) and "useful" or "correct". But yes, you can do this .

Comment: Joining `T2` twice without providing different table aliases, e.g. `T2 as T2FromT1` and `T2 as T2FromT3`,  for the two references doesn't look like a good thing. Which `T2` does the select list reference?

Answer (score 1):

It is "valid" but the `full join`s are not correct.  The `on` conditions will change them to some other type of `join`.

Your query has other errors.  But I speculate that you want:

```
select T1.[...], T2.[...], T3.[...]
from T1 full join
     T2 
     on T2.[key] = T1.[key] full join
     T3 join
     on T3.[key] = coalesce(T2.[key], T1.[key]);
```

Comment: I'm clearly missing something here, they look like normal FULL JOINs to me. I would think a normal commentor would be confusing CROSS JOIN and FULL JOIN but that seems really unlikely for you. Can you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock . . . If that comment is directed to me, I'm totally baffled.  Maybe you should consider asking your own question?

Comment: What do you mean about the ON conditions making them not FULL JOINs?

Comment: @AnthonyHancock . . . They do additional filtering due to `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to join three tables, and your example could run with some changes, but you have syntax and scoping errors in the FROM clause.

Even those aside, I don't think it will do what you intend it to do. You'll probably want to use GROUP BY

See the examples / discussion here :

[Multiple FULL OUTER JOIN on multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167902/multiple-full-outer-join-on-multiple-tables)

I also used this site as a source, as its been a while since I've touched SQL, it may be helpful to you also :

https://learnsql.com/blog/how-to-join-3-tables-or-more-in-sql/

Comment: . . Actually, the sample code will not run to do syntax errors and scoping errors in the `FROM` clause (that is, even if you expand the `...` into columns as the OP intends).

Comment: Ahh, I missed that. I was kinda hung up on the outer join bit/what OP was intending to do, as "The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword returns all records when there is a match in left (table1) or right (table2) table records." why use this as opposed to just using one or more full joins.